# Issue when comparing values in repeat section in Orbeon forms

Tags: orbeon, xforms

I am working on Orbeon forms and i have a functionality related issue as explained below.
I have a form which has repeat fields as below which is to be added dynamically by clicking on 'Add' button.
I have two fields in the repeat section.And also i have a condition like the fields must be compared with the one in the same row and also with the one which is in the previous and also in the next row.

I have an instance like this:

```
 1.constraint="if(.!='')
         then
       (. &lt; ../two and . &gt; ../preceding::number/two)
       else
       true()"/>
 2.constraint="if(.!='' )
    then 
    (. &gt; ../one  and . &lt; ../following-sibling::number/one)
    else
    true()"/>


 <number> is under repeat condition. 
 1.In this,i am trying to compare number/one with <two> in the same row and the     preceding row.
 2.In this,i am trying to compare number/two with <one> in the same row and the     next preceding row.

 I have to add like 10 times of these fields.When it is added after 3rd time,the logic doesn't work properly.

 Kindly let me know what happens in this case.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unqualified preceding-sibling and following-sibling xpath expressions return a sequence of **all** preceding or following siblings.

You need to add a predicate to select the previous or next sibling.

So, for your example:

```
../preceding-sibling::number[1]/two
```

or. more fully

```
../preceding-sibling::number[position()=1]/two
```

will return the previous sibling "two" element.

An example integer comparison:

```
(. > xs:integer(../preceding-sibling::number[1]/two))
```

See http://blog.orbeon.com/2007/06/xpath-reverse-axis-evil-at-times_04.html for more.

Regards

Jez

Comment: Could you be more specific?

Comment: When i am adding for about 10 times in the section i am getting issues in the 2nd,4th,7th and 10th row alone
Constraints are not shown in 2nd row,4th row, 7th row and 10 the row.
In other rows ,the code is working fine.

Can you explain why that happens.

Comment: It sounds like you could be doing string comparisons: ie ('9' > '8')=TRUE, ('10' > '9')=FALSE. See edited answer above.

Comment: Thank u so much for ur clear explanation.The code is working fine.